# Right Aligned elements not staying on one line

Tags: html, css, sass, angular-material

I want to place some elements on the left and some the right. But the elements on the right are not staying on line, especially after addition of mat-form-field. I'm getting:

[image]

On the right side, the Right Button and the Icon are on the same line, but the mat-form-field does not stay with them on the same line.

My html is:

```
<div class="mat-table-container">
    <div class="mat-table-button-wrapper">
        <div id="left-aligned-wrapper">
            <button class="btn btn-primary"> 
                Left Button
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="right-aligned-wrapper">
            <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
              <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
            </mat-form-field>
            <button type="button" mat-button>
              Right Button
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <i class="my-icon my-icon-filter"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.mat-table-container {
  position: relative;
  .mat-table-button-wrapper {
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 0em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    #left-aligned-wrapper {
      float: left;
    }  
    #right-aligned-wrapper {
      float: right;
    }
  }
}
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Some top margin on `mat-form-field`?

Comment: I copy pasted your code here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5r6u3p-nabsuj and it's working fine. Mat-form-field and Right button is coming at correct position. Check in developer tools if some other css is getting applied on any of those fields or not.

Comment: @Hemendra `width:auto` on the mat-form-field made the right side elements to be on same line now. But you can see in the slackblitz demo that the right side elements are on a lower side than the left side elements. Why is this happening? I'm getting this issue of right side being lower placed

Comment: you are using different controls in left-aligned and right-aligned divs,this is expected whenever there are controls from two different libraries. Left one is simple HTML button (left button) and right one is mat-form-field. mat-form-field expands the object in DOM and apply it's own CSS. If you don't want mat-form-field CSS to be applied, you can make use of ViewEncapsulation, read here - https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use `flexbox` instead of `float` in this situation.

This would result in your CSS looking something like this:

```
.mat-table-container {
  position: relative;
  .mat-table-button-wrapper {
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 0em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

i.e. removing applying `display: flex` to your wrapper class and using `justify-content: space-between` to space your content accordingly.

This would also make sure your content doesn't jump to the next 'line'.

Answer (score 1):

Please applied width: 50% in both elements.
Or use display: flex property.

```
.mat-table-button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-item: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```